# Save PDF from excel dynamically

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in Excel and have a macro to save the ActiveSheet as pdf. Is there anyway I can:

- Select the columns to be printed. Right now I just hide them.
- Save multiple pdf with the same name, concatenated by unique SKU: name_SKU.pdf
- A way to filter the column "SKU" and save the pdf for that SKU and automatically go to the next unique SKU and save the pdf and so on.

Currently I filter the SKU column manually and click on "Save PDF" macro each time. I want to reduce this task to a single click.

Comment: It is certainly possible to do.  It will also be easier for someone to show you how to amend your existing code if they can see the existing code.  Please paste the code into the question or you will find that your question gets downvoted for not providing it.

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways to do this.

First you can save each sheets print area to PDF using this function:

This function takes in fileName, which can be parsed from cell values as you want, the folder path for PDF's to be saved and sheet, from which the print area is taken.

```
Function PrintToPDF(fileName As String, folderPath As String, ByVal currentSheet As Worksheet)

currentSheet.Range(currentSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:= _
folderPath & fileName & "_SKU.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Function
```

Now you can edit the code a bit to print only custom ranges by adding additional argument to function:

```
Function PrintToPDF(fileName As String, folderPath As String, ByVal currentSheet As Worksheet, printRange As String)

currentSheet.Range(printRange).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:= _
folderPath & fileName & "_SKU.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Function
```

To use this function do something like this:

```
Sub test()
    Call PrintToPDF("name", "C:/Path/To/Folder/", Worksheets(1))
End Sub
```

Or in second case:

```
Sub test()
    Call PrintToPDF("1", "C:/Path/To/Folder/", Worksheets(1), "A1:C20")
End Sub
```

Now lets say you have a table with name values and sheet numbers (and ranges if you don't want to use print area):

```
TEST1    1
TEST2    2
TEST3    3
```

Then loop through your values in this table and call the function with cell values as arguments:

```
Sub test()
    For i = 1 To Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Call PrintToPDF(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value, "C:/Path/To/Folder/", Worksheets(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Or as how you like to define your names/sheets/ranges range.

Hope this helps!